# How to get rid of the bitterness in home-made mustard

Tags: mustard

**BASE FOR Q:**
I took 2:1 yellow, black mustard ratio, i dry-grounded only yellow part. Mixed all together. Made brine 1:1 apple cider vinegar/water. Added sugar and salt to taste a poured this liquid over the above metioned mustard mix. Let it soak.

It tasted bitter. I read billion of opinions. After week I got upset and just spread the entire batch in 1cm layer over big tray and let it breathe for 3 days. It did mellow big time. I put it into glass and it did mellow further over next months.

I wanted hot mustard so no cooking. Cooking makes mustard not hot.

**Q:**
Is it just time and air, or is there anything else and better scientific with explanations, what mellows and finally removes bitterness in homemade mustard?

How are theese super hot mustards made wiyhout being bitter at all?
**EDIT:** Superhot is when you dont cook the mustard at all, or for just a short time.

Comment: I solved the trouble by getting *better* mustard seed. It varies quite a bit. Not knowing the parameters, I threw money at the problem, and that worked. Someone will probably be along to tell you how to gauge seed quality before buying.

Comment: The difference between bitter quinoa and tasty quinoa is whether you rinse the quinoa first, presumably removing some bitter coating on the outside of the seed. This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but have you considered rinsing the mustard seed before processing it?

Answer (score 1):

I made an experiment, with tottaly different method and same ingredients.

The biggest change in bitterness is when seeds ground or whole, are soked in water. And there is no acid present.

1.) In bitter scenario I poured mixture of vinegar/water brine also all spices, sugar and salt over and made it ready mixture. It stayed bitter for long time.

2.) Not bitter ready to age scenario was that I added to the mix of seeds water from the recipe first and let it sit 24h. Than I added the rest of ingredients.

It would be great if someone can elaborate on this chemicaly.